# CSS transform hides floated element above it

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm making a simple blog post box with am image at the top. When the mouse hovers over the box the image scales to 1.1 and the overflow is hidden.

The blog post DIV is set to relative and I have icon above the image that is set to absolute so it sits half on the top of the image and half above it.

The problem:
When the mouse hoovers over the DIV, the images scales as it should but the part of the icon that sits over the image disappears.

How can I stop this, so that the icon remains visible when the scale transform is happening?

Thanks for the help.

HTML

```
<a href="#">
<div class="blog_slot">

<div class="blog_icon">
<img src="\adrenicon.jpg" style="width:50px; height:50px;" 

alt="adrenicon">
</div>

<div class="blog_image">
<img src="\image.jpg" alt="xxxxx">
</div>
<div class="blog_title">
<H2>xxx</H2>
<H3>xxxxxxxxx</H3>
</div>
<p>xxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
<p>...
<p>Read More</p>

</div>
</a>
```

and the CSS

```
.blog_icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;

}


.blog_slot    {
    position: relative;
    max-width:500px;
    min-width:200px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #FFD657;
    text-align: center;
    }

.blog_image
{

    overflow: hidden;}

.blog_image img {
    width:100%;
    max-width:450;
    height:100%;


  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;

}

.blog_slot:hover .blog_image img {

  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this solves your problem. I have added a `z-index` to `.blog-icon`.

```css
.blog_icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.blog_slot {
  position: relative;
  max-width:500px;
  min-width:200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #FFD657;
  text-align: center;
}

.blog_image {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blog_image img {
  width:100%;
  max-width:450;
  height:100%;

  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;

}

.blog_slot:hover .blog_image img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
<div class="blog_slot">

<div class="blog_icon">
<img src="https://unsplash.it/50/60/?random" style="width:50px; height:50px;" alt="adrenicon">
</div>

<div class="blog_image">
<img src="https://unsplash.it/800/1200/?random" alt="xxxxx">
</div>
<div class="blog_title">
<H2>xxx</H2>
<H3>xxxxxxxxx</H3>
</div>
<p>xxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
<p>...
<p>Read More</p>

</div>
</a>
```

Comment: perfect, so simple and so effective! Thank you